# How to add data from one database to another based on a numerical and character conditional

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I am trying to add an extra column onto a database `df2` based on information from another database `df1`. I have one column called `sequence_annotation` in `df2` if this column has a numerical value then I want it to copy the information in a column called `PoleX` and `AnX` for characters. The column/identifier that is constant for both databases is called `CTsite` so this is how I am matching up which values from `PoleX` or `AnX` should be added.

df2 looks like this:

```
CTsite  sequence_annotation
OCCAJ01  Lt
OCCAJ01  20
OCCAJ04  Mt
OCCAJ04  40
```

df1 looks like this:

```
CTsite   AnX  Pole X    
OCCAJ01  720  2592
OCCAJ04  640  3264
```

The disired output is:

```
CTsite sequence_annotation  xres
OCCAJ01  Lt                 720  
OCCAJ01  20                 2592
OCCAJ04  Mt                 640
OCCAJ04  40                 3264
```

I have tried to create a code base on previous questions and comments but it doesn't work. Would be very grateful if anyone can help. This is the code:

```
if (mode(df2$sequence_annotation)=="numeric") {
df2$xres <- df1$PoleX[match(df1$CTsite,df2$CTsite)]
} else {
df2$xres <- df1$AnX[match(df1$CTsite, df2$CTsite)]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Hi Cath, thanks for the links. I am new to coding and dyslexic so I find it hard to explain my problem. I am not sure how to explain it better perhaps adding an example of my dataframes?

Comment: Data examples (input and desired output) would make it easier to see what you have and what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different solution with tidyverse. I suspect that your test of being numeric being inadequate : all the values of the column must share the same mode, probably character as in the following :

```
library(reader)
library(stringr)

df2 <- read_csv("
CTsite  ,sequence_annotation
OCCAJ01 ,Lt
OCCAJ01 ,20
OCCAJ04 ,Mt
OCCAJ04 ,40",skip=1)
df1 <- read_csv("
CTsite   ,AnX  ,PoleX    
OCCAJ01  ,720  ,2592
OCCAJ04  ,640  ,3264",skip=1)

df2 %>% inner_join(df1,by="CTsite") %>%
   mutate(xres=ifelse(str_detect(sequence_annotation,"\\D"),AnX,PoleX))

## A tibble: 4 x 5
#  CTsite  sequence_annotation   AnX PoleX     a
#  <chr>   <chr>               <int> <int> <int>
#1 OCCAJ01 Lt                    720  2592   720
#2 OCCAJ01 20                    720  2592  2592
#3 OCCAJ04 Mt                    640  3264   640
#4 OCCAJ04 40                    640  3264  3264
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I tried this way before, it does add the column `xres` but all the values are all NA.

Comment: Perhaps because the test mode(...)=="numeric" returns NA? It is difficult to say without any view on data.

Comment: I just ran it on its own and this was the output `(mode(df2$sequence_annotation)=="numeric")`
`[1] TRUE`    I have edited the question with an example of what the data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

The dplyr-package could help. But as I cannot reproduce that, I cannot much help. Here is a cheat sheet

https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf